# mailjet with brimir (open source Ruby project) on debian doesn't send mail

Tags: debian, email, postfix, smtp, ruby

I tired of searching a tip to be able to send mails with mailjet on my debian.

I configured a dashboard for tickets (Brimir, Ruby open source plateform)

Here is the link : https://github.com/ivaldi/brimir

The installation was easy, and it works like a charm. Unfortunatly, **i'm not able to configure Brimir with mailjet. While when we create a ticket on Brimir, notification is NORMALLY sent by mail to the agents but I don't receive any mails ?**. I used this documentation :

https://fr.mailjet.com/docs/code/ruby

**Here the config of my MTA (POSTFIX)**

```
myhostname = in-v3.mailjet.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination =
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/32 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4

smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
```

**The sasl_passwd contains a string like**

```
in-v3.mailjet.com secret_key
```

**and in the Ruby App, there is the configuration :**

```
#config/application.rb

config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :mailjet


#config/initializers/mailjet.rb

Mailjet.configure do |config|
      config.api_key = 'your-api-key'
      config.secret_key = 'your-secret-key'
      config.default_from = 'my_registered_mailjet_email@domain.com'
end
```

**and I replaced the default values by my mailjet account values.**

Don't know if it will be useful, but **the guy that worked before me blocked all the mails incomming** because our SMTP relay was attacked and used for spamming customers. I copy/paste the config below :

```
strict_rfc821_envelopes = yes
disable_vrfy_command = yes
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_client_restrictions =
smtpd_helo_restrictions =
smtpd_sender_restrictions =
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
    permit_sasl_authenticated,
    reject_unauth_destination,
    reject_invalid_hostname,
    reject_unauth_pipelining,
    reject_non_fqdn_sender,
    reject_unknown_sender_domain,
    reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
    reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
    check_client_access hash:$config_directory/access_client,
    check_sender_access hash:$config_directory/access_sender
    permit
```

Comment: Check your Rails logs.

Comment: I use the apache mod_rails. So I checked apache2 logs, nothing about this. When I check mails with "mail -u www-data" or "mail -u root", the response is "No mail for root"...